# Contact area size in MultitouchSupport private framework

Tags: macos-carbon, multi-touch, ellipse

I've been playing around with the carbon multitouch support private framework and I've been able to retrieve various type of data.

Among these, each contact seems to have a size and is as well described by an ellipsoid (angle, minor axis, major axis). However, I haven't been able to identify the frame of reference used for the size and the minor and major axis.

If anybody has been able to find it out, I'm interested in your information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what "carbon multi-touch framework is" but what you described are parameters from a [TUIO](http://tuio.org/?specification) tracker for an object or a blob. But they are rarely used.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. The multitouch support framework is a private framework from apple. It means it is accessible in the library, but it has no header file and it is not documented. By retro-engineering the framework, some have been able to get more informations ( http://hci.rwth-aachen.de/tiki-index.php?page=guide_trackpad&offset=&sort_mode=comment_asc&atts_show=y ). However, no way to find the unit used for size and minor axis/major axis. I really would love to be able to get the exact contact area surface.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the framework for two years now and I've found that the ellipse is not in standard units (e.g. inches, milimeters). You could approximate millimeters by doubling the values you get for the ellipse.

Here's how I derived the ellipse information.

First, my best guess for how it works is that it's close to Synaptics "units per mm": http://ccdw.org/~cjj/l/docs/ACF126.pdf But since Apple has not released any of that information for developers, I'm relying on information that I print to the console.

You may get slightly different values based on the dimensions of the device (e.g. native trackpad vs magic mouse) you're using with the MultiTouchSupport.framework. This might also be caused by the differences in the surface (magic mouse is curved).

The code on http://www.steike.com/code/multitouch/ has a parameter called `mm`. This gives you the raw (non-normalized) position and velocity for the device.

Based on the width's observed min & max values from `mm` (-47.5,52.5), the trackpad is ~100 units wide (~75 units the other way). The trackpad is about 100mm wide x 80mm. But no, it's not a direct unit to millimeter translation. I think the parameter being named 'mm' may have just been a coincidence.

My forearm can cover about 90% of the surface of the trackpad. After laying it across the trackpad, the output will read to about 58 units wide by 36 units long, with a `size` of 55. If you double the units you get 116 by 72 which is really close to 100mm by 80mm. So that's why I say just double the units to approximate the millimeters. I've done this with my forearm the other way and with my palm and the approximations still seem to work.

The size of 55 doesn't seem to coincide with the values of `ellipse`. I'm inclined to believe that `ellipse` is an approximation of the surface dimensions and `size` is the actual surface area (probably in decimeters).

Sorry there's no straight answer (this is after all a reverse engineering project) but maybe this information can help you find the answer yourself.

(Note: I'd like to know what you're working on?)